# The size of checkbox django is very huge

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

[image]I am creating a checkbox for subscribing using forms.py in Django. The size of the checkbox is very huge I don't why.

Models.py:

```
receive_notification = models.BooleanField('Receivenotification',default=True)
```

Forms.py:

```
receive_notification = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

The CSS file:

```
        h8 {    width: 320px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 710px; 
    position: absolute;
    }
```

The HTML file:

```
  <h8>

                    {{ field.label }}
                     {{ field }}

                    </h8>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Django issue related, it's a CSS problem.

If you're not good with CSS you can use Django Bootstrap Forms.

First you install it into your virtual environment

```
pip install django-bootstrap-form
```

Then register your `apps` in the file `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'bootstrapform',
    ...
)
```

Then you use that on your template

```
{% load bootstrap %}

{{ form|bootstrap }}
```

See [here](https://django-bootstrap-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more information